# Python process merge results

Tags: python, set, python-multiprocessing

I am currently trying to implement a class to do intensive calculus :

```
import random
import multiprocessing as mp


class IntensiveStuff:

    def __init__(self):
        self.N = 20
        self.nb_process = 4
        set_of_things = set()

    def lunch_multiprocessing(self):
        processes = []
        for i in range(self.nb_process):
            processes.append(mp.Process(target=self.process_method, args=()))
        [x.start() for x in processes]
        [x.join() for x in processes]
        set_of_things = ... # I want all the sub_set of 'process_method' updated in set_of_things

    def process_method(self):
        sub_set = set()
        for _ in range(self.N):
            sub_set.add(random.randint(100))
```

I want to compute independent calculus, put the results in a sub_set for each process and merge all the sub_set in the set_of_things (which are object in the real code).

I have trying to use Queue without success, any advise ?

P.S : have tried to reproduce the code in [Can a set() be shared between Python processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714680/can-a-set-be-shared-between-python-processes) but without any luck as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Processes can't share memory, but they may communicate via Pipes, sockets, etc. multiprocessing module has special objects (i believe, they use pipes under the hood). multiprocessing.Queue should also work, but I use often these two objects:

multiprocessing.Manager().list() and
multiprocessing.Manager().dict()

```
results = multiprocessing.Manager().list()
# now a bit of your code
processes = []
for i in range(self.nb_process):
   processes.append(mp.Process(target=self.process_method, args=(), results))

def process_method(self, results):
    sub_set = set()
    for _ in range(self.N):
        sub_set.add(random.randint(100))
    results.append(sub_set) # or what you really need to add to results
```

Comment: Shared memory in Python with multiprocessing is perfectly [possible](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

Comment: The results = multiprocessing.Manager().list() did what I want, thanks !

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis, yes, but it's not "real" shared memory. I described it from processes definition.

Comment: Yes and since I call a method within my class the performance are not enhanced.